# How to pass function from Parent to Child when you already have proptypes in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

I am trying to pass a method as props to the child class. 
Error: this.props.funcName is not a function.

```
class Poll extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      customPollReq: false,
      isPolling: false,
      customPollValues: [],
    };
    this.inputEditor = [];
    this.renderCustomMView = this.renderCustomMView.bind(this);
  }
.
.
.
renderCustomMView() {
    const { intl, startCustomPoll } = this.props;
    const isDisabled = _.compact(this.inputEditor).length < 1;
    if (this.inputEditor.length > 0) {
              Session.set('pollInitiated', true);
              this.setState({ isPolling: true }, () => 
              startCustomPoll('custom', _.compact(this.inputEditor)));
            }
render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Video funcName={this.renderCustomMView} />
            </div>

const poll = Poll;
const withInjectIntl = injectIntl(Poll);
export { poll as Poll };
export default withModalMounter(withInjectIntl);


Poll.propTypes = {
  intl: PropTypes.shape({
    formatMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
  amIPresenter: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  pollTypes: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array).isRequired,
  startPoll: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  startCustomPoll: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  stopPoll: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Child

```
class VideoPlayer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
.
.
.
    const { isPresenter } = props;
    this.newFuncCall = this.newFuncCall.bind(this);

.
.    
.
newFuncCall(){     
                console.log("12345");
                this.props.funcName();
        }

.
.
const video = VideoPlayer;
export {video as Video};
export default injectIntl(injectWbResizeEvent(VideoPlayer));
```

When I try to call the function in my child class as "this.props.funcName()", it shows this.props.funcName is not a function. I am also using **prop-types**. Is it affecting the code? When I wrote a hello world program and implemented this child-parent inheritance, it worked well.

I am totally clueless.

this.props in Video Component

[image: this.porps in Video Component]

Answer (score 2):

You passed it as funcName props. So you can call it `this.props.funcName()`

Comment: Can you post Video component too?

Comment: I found a mistake. You passed it `this.renderCustomMView` instead of `this.renderCustomView`. It is typo issue, isn't it?

Comment: My bad. While copying the code I missed that 'M'. It's this.renderCustomMView .

Comment: Please post what you log `this.props` of Video component in console.

Comment: Done. Please check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214883/discussion-between-topwebghost-and-ayushman-kumar).